# How to route all traffic through https?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

Service Fabric allows you to specify what endpoints it will listen on, and each service can expose different protocols like so:

```
            protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp,
                    serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpointHttps")),

                 //you can add another one here like so:
new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp,
                    serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpointUnSecured"))
            };
        }
```

In the ServiceManifest.xml file, we can specify these two endpoints:

```
<Endpoints>
        <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpointUnsecured" Type="Input" />
  <Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="ServiceEndpointHttps" Type="Input" />
</Endpoints>
```

We have 100 microservices, and we want to have **only 1, central location** where we configure whether the services are running through http or https.

**Is it possible to change this setup so that we would have only 1 location that would be responsible for routing http or https for ALL services?**

Comment: Well you could use the built-in reverse proxy.. that may or may not work for your use case, only you know that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy-configure-secure-communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you are talking about communication between services within the cluster or from outside the cluster there are a few different approaches.

For service to service communication inside the cluster, it's all up to the client (e.g. the other service making the call). The reverse proxy, as Rogala mentions, would be the central solution. You can call the reverse proxy and it will use the Service Fabric naming service to route to the exposed endpoint. If you only expose https, it will be https, you can also configure the reverse proxy to always use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy-configure-secure-communication

For ingress to the cluster, a similar concept, having everything going through a gateway service inside the cluster, is the common pattern. The gateway service would then use the reverse proxy and thus the pattern described above: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#connections-from-external-clients

Comment: external is what im looking for. so according to the article (your second link), i would have a service listening on regular http, and then it would make calls to the services internally? it would be like a router?

Comment: Yes, the reverse proxy can do so today, but cannot be configured to only expose certain services or the URL host / path to expose them on. We are working on a better built-in gateway solution in the next months.

Comment: what would be the best way to turn off https? let's assume that the services are configured to expose both http and https. what is the best / easiest way to turn off regular http from one central location rather than having to do it in every service?

Comment: There is no way of doing this centrally as each service is autonomous.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could use a proxy like Apigee or Azure API management and have all traffic proxy through that central location. This provides major advantages around security and managing traffic.

Comment: i'm actually using on-premise, i believe that SF should have a solution to this. in any case, for this solution i would have to have all the services deployed to both http and https for this to work

Comment: Also, I know Azure Functions has a proxy in preview, but I don't know if it is available in Azure Stack (assuming you are using Azure Stack)  Also, if you are using Azure Stack, API management may or may not be available.  They planned to make it available this year based on this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20bcf79c-f04a-4e6f-a1b2-f7a2152dd842/api-management-on-azure-stack?forum=azureapimgmt

Comment: The person that down-voted my answer, please provide a reason.  Utilizing a proxy service to mange 100 microservices is a very valid solution.